# Why is there a difference in output when using Event Control Statement and Delay statement for a simple D Flipflop?

Tags: verilog, simulation, fpga, system-verilog, quartus

I have created a testbench for a simple positive edge triggered d flip flop with synchronous active-low reset. In the testbench, the first case gives inputs at `@(posedge clk)`, and in the second case, I am giving inputs based on `#10ns` statements.

In the first case, the output of the flop changes after 1 clock cycle, whereas in the second case, it changes immediately in the same clock cycle in the simulator.

Why?

I am simulating in the Quartus Simulator.

Code:

```
initial
begin
    //Case 1: Using Event Based statements
    n_reset = 1'b0;
    reset = 1'b1;
    d = 1'b0;
    repeat(2)@(posedge clk);
    n_reset = 1'b1;
    repeat(2)@(posedge clk);
    d = 1'b1;
    @(posedge clk);
    d = 1'b0;
    @(posedge clk);
    d = 1'b1;
    
    //Case 2: Using wait Statement
    #50ns;
    n_reset = 1'b0;
    reset = 1'b1;
    d = 1'b0;
    #50ns;
    n_reset = 1'b1;
    #20ns;
    d = 1'b1;
    #10ns;
    d = 1'b0;
    #10ns;
    d = 1'b1;
    #50ns;
    
end
```

[image: Waveform of D FlipFlop with the testbench]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Using wait Statement:**

Delays the execution of a procedural statement by specific simulation time.

"**#<_time> <_statement>;**"

**Using Event Based statements:**

Delays execution of the next statement until the specified transition on a signal.

**@ (< posedge >|< negedge > signal) < statement >;**

**Level-Sensitive Even Controls ( Wait statements ):**

Delays execution of the next statement until < expression > evaluates to true

**wait (< expression >) < statement >;**

Now I think you are able to differentiate, Right?

Answer (score 0):

You see differences because there are simulation race conditions in the testbench.

Let's assume your flipflop uses the recommended coding style, something like this:

```
always @(posedge clk) q <= d;
```

`q` is the flipflop output.  It is important to note that the flipflop uses a nonblocking assignment (`<=`).

The testbench code uses blocking assignments (`=`) everywhere.  Let's also assume you are always changing `d` at the same time as the `clk` rising edge when you use `#` delays.  When that is the case, you have a race condition no matter what type of timing control you are using (Case 1 or Case 2).  Although you are seeing a difference between the two cases, there is no **guarantee** that you will see a difference because of the race.

Since the testbench uses blocking and the design (flipflop) use nonblocking, the value of `d` that is sampled inside the design is indeterminate.

The best way to avoid the race condition and to guarantee that the `d` input is synchronous to `clk` is to use nonblocking assignments in the testbench:

```
repeat(2) @(posedge clk);
d <= 1'b1;
@(posedge clk);
d <= 1'b0;
```